# Specify max delimiter with delim_whitespace, read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following results in a variable called *results*:

```py
data = """
0 a b this is my first file
1 c d this is my second file
2 e f this is my third file
3 g h this is my fourth file
4 i j this is my fifth file
"""
```

I want to parse the results into a pandas DataFrame.
The result I want is

###### Calling read_csv

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | b | this is my first file |
| 1 | c | d | this is my second file |
| 2 | e | f | this is my third file |

Instead, when I called:

***read_csv(StringIO(results), delim_whitespace=True)***, I get :

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | b | this | is | my | first | file |
| 1 | c | d | this | is | my | second | file |
| 2 | e | f | this | is | my | third | file |

Is there any way to specify the **max number of delimiter while using delim_whitespace** ?

Comment: could you use `.split()`  on the lines in the results variable? For example if `line = 'a b this is my first file'`; `line.split(' ',2)` returns `['a', 'b', 'this is my first file']`

Comment: show the code that stores your `results` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Data
results = """a b this is my first file
c d this is my second file
e f this is my third file
g h this is my fourth file
i j this is my fifth file"""

lines = results.split("\n")
words = [line.split(maxsplit=2) for line in lines]
df = pd.DataFrame(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
data = """0 a b this is my first file
1 c d this is my second file
2 e f this is my third file
3 g h this is my fourth file
4 i j this is my fifth file"""

data = [line.split(' ', 3) for line in data.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   0  1  2                       3
0  0  a  b   this is my first file
1  1  c  d  this is my second file
2  2  e  f   this is my third file
3  3  g  h  this is my fourth file
4  4  i  j   this is my fifth file
```